# Is there any way to generate values for testing this way in Haskell QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have 2 data types that I use for the representation of natural numbers in the unary system

```
data Valoare_Unar = Unu deriving(Show);
data Numar_Unar = Invalid | Unar [Valoare_Unar] deriving(Show);
```

I have those functions for converting this number from Integer to my data type and vice-versa.

```
convert :: Unar.Numar_Unar -> Integer
convert Unar.Invalid = (-1)
convert (Unar.Unar xs)
    | null xs   = 0
    | otherwise = 1 + convert (Unar.Unar (tail xs))

convert' :: Integer -> Unar.Numar_Unar
convert' (-1) = Unar.Invalid
convert' x = fromInteger x :: Unar.Numar_Unar
```

I want to test that `(convert' (convert _)) == _` and I have
`prop_check xs = Utils.convert' (Utils.convert xs) == xs where types = xs::Unar.Numar_Unar` for that.

I've made my data types instances of Arbitrary but I had problems figuring out how I should generate values for the "Unar" constructor.

```
instance Arbitrary Valoare_Unar where
        arbitrary = elements [Unu]

instance Arbitrary Numar_Unar where
    arbitrary = elements [Invalid, Unar []]
```

Using `QC.verboseCheck prop_check` I've noticed that the only test values are "Invalid" and "Unar[]".

My question is: How could I generate values like "Unar[Unu] ; Unar[Unu,Unu,Unu] ; ... ; Unar [Unu,..,Unu]" for testing ?

EDIT: instance Num Numar_Unar

```
instance Num Numar_Unar where
    (+) (Unar xs) (Unar ys)
        | null ys   = (Unar xs)
        | otherwise = (+) (Unar (xs ++ [head ys])) (Unar (tail ys))
    (+) _ _ = Invalid
    (-) (Unar xs) (Unar ys)
        | length xs < length ys = Invalid
        | null ys               = Unar xs
        | xs == ys              = Unar []
        | otherwise             = (-) (Unar (tail xs)) (Unar (tail ys))
    (-) _ _ = Invalid
    (*) (Unar xs) (Unar ys)
        | null ys   = Unar []
        | otherwise = (+) (Unar xs) ((*) (Unar xs) (Unar (tail ys)))
    (*) _ _ = Invalid
    abs (Unar xs)   = Unar xs
    abs Invalid     = Invalid

    signum (Unar xs)
        | null xs   = Unar []
        | otherwise = Unar [Unu]
    signum Invalid  = Invalid
    fromInteger x 
        | x < 0     = Invalid
        | x == 0    = Unar []
        | otherwise = (+) (Unar [Unu]) (fromInteger (x-1))
```

Comment: This code looks a bit like a cross between C and Lisp. Using `-1` to represent an invalid value is really not idiomatic, and using partial functions like `tail` is discouraged in situations where pattern matching can easily do the job.

Comment: I just started learning Haskell and actually, this is the first time learning a functional programming language so the code surely looks rusty for those who worked with it a lot.

I've posted the instance Num Numar_Unar

Comment: `arbitrary = elements [Invalid, Unar []]` means "when I run `arbitrary` on this type, always give me `Invalid` or `Unar []`". Why did you write that if that's not what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understood what that means... but I can't figure out how to make that when I run arbitrary to give me `Invalid` or a random `Unar` number.. What function should I use or how should I try to generate that list of `Unar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arbitrary = elements [Invalid, Unar []]` means "when I run `arbitrary` on this type, always give me `Invalid` or `Unar []`". A proper `Arbitrary` instance looks like this:

```
instance Arbitrary Numar_Unar where
    arbitrary = frequency [(1, return Invalid), (3, Unar <$> arbitrary)]
```

This will make `arbitrary` generate `Invalid` 1/4 of the time and `Unar` 3/4 of the time. When it generates `Unar`, it will call `arbitrary` for the `[Valoare_Unar]` type to get a list with a random number of elements instead of always none. You should also consider adding a `shrink` method to the class, like this:

```
    shrink Invalid = []
    shrink (Unar []) = [Invalid]
    shrink (Unar (Unu:xs)) = [Invalid, Unar [], Unar xs]
```